# How to configure routing and controllers for user roles

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I have a profile page that I am displaying to all users at the url `/profile/foo` however once it loads, I am doing some checks to determine if the user viewing that profile is the owner of it. If so I would like to display an edit button that within the same page will display another view and change the route to `/profile/foo/edit` however I would like to restrict anything from showing at `/profile/foo/edit` if that user is not the owner or if the owner did not view `/profile/foo` first since the controller that loads all the profile information is configured to that route.

I know for sure that the controller that handles the editing as well as the editing interface for /profile/foo/edit will have to be lazy loaded depending on whether the user is the owner of the profile.

I am initially not running a .config on my module to setup routing because I dont know if the user is the owner so I had to hard code the ng-controller onto a DOM element that really should be an ng-view but initially cannot since I dont want to load the editing view partial.

So here is my question how can I setup this kind of routing at runtime (switch controllers and views) as well as actually load the controller and the view. Only if the user is the owner of the profile.

Comment: did you setup routing for /profile/:userid or /profile/foo?? if it :userid, then it is a generic one, which shouldn't be removed. if you want to setup routing for /profile/foo for user foo and /bar for user bar, then you should let user login first and then redirect to angular app to setup routing by logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to doing this.  My Strong suggestion is to use ui-router as it's the defacto recommended third-party plugin for managing routes in Angular projects.

Then you would lock down routes using the route config like this:

```
  $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'scripts/home/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        access: access.public
      })
      .when('/projects', {
        templateUrl: 'scripts/project/project.html',
        controller: 'ProjectCtrl',
        access: access.user
      })
      .when('/projects/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'scripts/project/project-detail.html',
        controller: 'ProjectDetailCtrl',
        access: access.user
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }]);
```

Then on route change you would check the route:

```
angular.module('app').run(['$rootScope','$location','security', function($rootScope, $location, security) {
    // Get the current user when the application starts
    // (in case they are still logged in from a previous session)
    security.requestCurrentUser();

    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
        if (!security.authorize(next.access)) {
            $location.path('/');
        }
    });

}]);
```

Using some sort of security service:

```
 authorize: function(accessLevelReq) {
            if (_.isNull(service.currentUserAccessLevels)) {
                populateUserAccessLevels('public');
            }

            var authenticated = false;
            _.each(accessLevelReq, function(value){
                if(service.currentUserAccessLevels[value]) {
                    authenticated = true;
                }
            });
            return authenticated;
        }
```

Luckily I have a seed project which illustrates this exact use case. https://github.com/thinkjones/meanp-seed